# Applying function to pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, geocoding

I have a pandas dataframe called 'tourdata' consisting of 676k rows of data. Two of the columns are latitude and longitude.

Using the reverse_geocode package I want to convert these coordinates to a country data.

When I call :

```
import reverse_geocode as rg

tourdata['Country'] = rg.search((row[tourdata['latitude']],row[tourdata['longitude']]))
```

I get the error :

> ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 coordinates = (tourdata['latitude'],tourdata['longitude']),
>   ----> 2 tourdata['Country'] = rg.search((row[tourdata['latitude']],row[tourdata['longitude']]))
>
> ~/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reverse_geocode/**init**.py
>   in search(coordinates)
>       114     """
>       115     gd = GeocodeData()
>   --> 116     return gd.query(coordinates)
>       117 
>       118
>
> ~/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reverse_geocode/**init**.py
>   in query(self, coordinates)
>        46         except ValueError as e:
>        47             logging.info('Unable to parse coordinates: {}'.format(coordinates))
>   ---> 48             raise e
>        49         else:
>        50             results = [self.locations[index] for index in indices]
>
> ~/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reverse_geocode/**init**.py
>   in query(self, coordinates)
>        43         """
>        44         try:
>   ---> 45             distances, indices = self.tree.query(coordinates, k=1)
>        46         except ValueError as e:
>        47             logging.info('Unable to parse coordinates: {}'.format(coordinates))
>
> ckdtree.pyx in scipy.spatial.ckdtree.cKDTree.query()
>
> ValueError: x must consist of vectors of length 2 but has shape (2,
>   676701)

To test that the package is working :

```
coordinates = (tourdata['latitude'][0],tourdata['longitude'][0]),
results = (rg.search(coordinates))
print(results)
```

Outputs :

```
[{'country_code': 'AT', 'city': 'Wartmannstetten', 'country': 'Austria'}]
```

Any help with this appreciated. Ideally I'd like to access the resulting dictionary and apply only the country code to the Country column.

Comment: typically in python you apply function to all items using map() but I have very little exp with pandas - so might be different

Comment: `tourdata['country'] = tourdata.apply(lambda x: rg.search(x['latitude'], x['longitude']), axis=1)`  ?

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston - when I try this I get :

`TypeError: ('search() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given', 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: Seems like you need, `tourdata['country'] = tourdata.apply(lambda x: rg.search(tuple([x['latitude'], x['longitude'])]), axis=1)` ?

Comment: Thank you @HarvIpan - I get the following this time : `TypeError: ('tuple() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)', 'occurred at index 0')
`

Comment: Are you sure you are passing a list ? Notice the `[` and `]` inside `tuple()`?

Comment: Thanks @HarvIpan -  The first parenthesis after longitude is causing a syntax error - when I remove it, I then get `TypeError: ("'int' object is not iterable", 'occurred at index 0')
`

Comment: try `tourdata['country'] = tourdata.apply(lambda row: rg.search((row['latitude'], row['longitude']))['country_code'], axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search method expects a list of coordinates. To obtain a single data point you can use "get" method.

Try :

```
tourdata['country'] = tourdata.apply(lambda x: rg.get((x['latitude'], x['longitude'])), axis=1)
```

It works fine for me :

```
import pandas as pd
tourdata = pd.DataFrame({'latitude':[0.3, 2, 0.6], 'longitude':[12, 5, 0.8]})
tourdata['country'] = tourdata.apply(lambda x: rg.get((x['latitude'], x['longitude'])), axis=1)
tourdata['country']
```

Output :

```
0    {'country': 'Gabon', 'city': 'Booué', 'country...
1    {'country': 'Sao Tome and Principe', 'city': '...
2    {'country': 'Ghana', 'city': 'Mumford', 'count...
Name: country, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works! Ideally I'd like to pull through just the Country name into the column, would you know the best way to do this?

Comment: Yes,the return of the method is a dict, so you just have to pass the name of the element you want to extract. 
Try this :
    tourdata['country'] = tourdata.apply(lambda x: rg.get((x['latitude'], x['longitude']))['country'], axis=1).

Comment: Thank you again, really appreciate it